# Use AES encryption inside a user defined function

Tags: php, aes

I need to use the AES encryption tool within a user defined function so as to access it many times in a file.

```
$sms = 'UF4niWyCEYBTEF2ELU+B2yBZT+ivehO+VXtDoalPPqg=';

decode($sms);    //the function below
$dec = decode($sms);
//echo "After encryption: ".$enc."<br/>";
echo "After decryption: ".$dec."<br/>";

function decode($sms) {
include 'AES.php';  //this is my AES file copied from the AES website
$inputText = $sms;
$inputKey = '_______'; //this is the underscore key pressed 7 times.
$blockSize = 256;
$aes = new AES($inputText, $inputKey, $blockSize);
$enc = $aes->encrypt();
$aes->setData($enc);
$dec=$aes->decrypt();

return $dec;
}
```

I have tried various attempt with the code above and searching for functions within function but I failing to parse the AES part to be error free. I'm usually receiving back a 'Cannot redeclare class AES in /home/myfile'

Answer (score 0):

The error you get from PHP `Cannot redeclare class AES in /home/myfile` is correct: by using [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) inside the function, PHP will attempt to include the file *each time you call the function*.

In the code below, the 'include' statement has been moved outside your function:

```
$sms = 'UF4niWyCEYBTEF2ELU+B2yBZT+ivehO+VXtDoalPPqg=';

decode($sms);    //the function below
$dec = decode($sms);
//echo "After encryption: ".$enc."<br/>";
echo "After decryption: ".$dec."<br/>";

include 'AES.php';  //this is my AES file copied from the AES website
function decode($sms) {
    $inputText = $sms;
    $inputKey = '_______'; //this is the underscore key pressed 7 times.
    $blockSize = 256;
    $aes = new AES($inputText, $inputKey, $blockSize);
    $enc = $aes->encrypt();
    $aes->setData($enc);
    $dec=$aes->decrypt();
    
    return $dec;
}
```

This should solve the error you mentioned.

Comment: I did this and received back a different error: Class 'AES' not found in /home/myfolder/Address... I do have the AES.php in the same folder as the file running the code above but I guess it can't see AES.php as it is outside the function? Any other suggestion pls?

Comment: try: `include __DIR__'/AES.php';` but really, you should open a new question for the new error.